# How set multiple cookies with res.cookie(key , value) on NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

I'm working with cookies on NodeJS and I wonder how set multiple cookies to send on client.

I have tried :

1-

```
     var headers = {
      Cookie: 'key1=value1; key2=value2'
  }
  res.cookie(headers)
```

2-

```
res.cookie("isStillHere" , 'yes it is !').send('Cookie is set');
res.cookie("IP" , ip).send('Cookie is set');
```

3-

```
  var setMultipleCookies =  []
 setMultipleCookies.push('key1=value1','key2=value2')
  res.cookie(setMultipleCookies)
```

Seems nothing works. What is going wrong ? Any hint would be great,

thanks

Comment: Are you using `Connect/Express` framework?

Comment: @m1ch4is yes I am using Express

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You simply call [`cookie`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.cookie) more than once **without** calling [`send`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send) in between them. Call `send` only after you've done all the cookies, since `send` sends the response body, and cookie headers are...well...in the header. :-)

```
res.cookie("isStillHere" , 'yes it is !');
res.cookie("IP" , ip);
res.send('Cookie is set');
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set all cookies before you call `res.send()`

```
res.cookie("isStillHere" , 'yes it is !');
res.cookie("IP" , ip);
res.send('Cookie is set');
```

Answer (score 2):

ShortHand (not so short), piping the functions.

```
res.cookie('cookie1' : { name: 'Leo' }).cookie('cookie2' : 'Teste').send()
```